# Applying time.sleep on each element of a python list

Tags: python

I want to independently iterate elements of a list in a marathon-like formation, such that each lane/element can move at a random/varied pace.

In order to still be able to access each element by index, I tried the following code:

```
cyclists = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']            #each elements represent an athlete

choose_athlete = random.choices((range(len(cyclists))), k=len(cyclists))    # index select athlete from elements/lane
################################################################
def circular_shifts(runners, step=1):
    step %= min(len(e) for e in runners)
    return [e[step:] + e[:step] for e in runners]


for laps in range(10):
    for i in range(len(cyclists)):
        cycling = circular_shifts(cyclists, i)
        print(cycling)
```

**#Problem:**::
#is there a way I can apply the concept of `time.sleep` to each element as they loop so I can determine their speed of running, i.e while lane1/element[0] is looping fast, lane2 is slower, and so on?

**Another example:**

```
cyclists = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']            #each elements represent an athlete

for i in range(5):
    for aa in cyclists[0]: 
        time.sleep(0)
        print(aa)

    for bb in cyclists[1]: 
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print(bb)

    for cc in cyclists[1]: 
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(cc)

    for dd in cyclists[1]: 
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print(dd)

    for ee in cyclists[0]: 
        time.sleep(0.4)
        print(ee)
```

But this approach print separately, instead, i want the output to still show up together as list so i can access them with index ([0:4])

Preferred output:

```
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
['cdeab', 'hijfg', 'mnokl', 'rstpq', 'wxyuv']
['deabc', 'ijfgh', 'noklm', 'stpqr', 'xyuvw']
['eabcd', 'jfghi', 'oklmn', 'tpqrs', 'yuvwx']
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
['cdeab', 'hijfg', 'mnokl', 'rstpq', 'wxyuv']
['deabc', 'ijfgh', 'noklm', 'stpqr', 'xyuvw']
['eabcd', 'jfghi', 'oklmn', 'tpqrs', 'yuvwx']
```

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you want to accomplish with your code, and what part of the current code is "not working". For each runner, they have a certain speed assigned? Then you want to determine which runner reaches the finish first? Do you want to use `time.sleep` because you want to illustrate this in the printout somehow?

Comment: the current code is actually working but i just need to add time.sleep or any other method so that each element iterate at different speed. for instance if list[0] takes time.sleep(0.001), list[1] move at time.sleep(0.002) etc

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to slow down the for loops by adding time.sleep, just do that. What is the problem, what are you trying to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not compute the distance travelled for each athlete at each iteration.  So if each iteration represents say, 5 minutes, an athlete who runs at 5min/km pace will have run 1km in iteration 1, 2km in iteration 2 etc.  Faster runners will have covered more distance based on their pace, likewise slower runners will have covered less distance.

Comment: sounds good. any pointer on that pls

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like "sleep sort"

Answer (score 1):

The way this was set up was a bit too confusing to me, so I coded up my own version of how a race could happen using `time.sleep`. I tried to add lots of comments to explain all the steps:

```py
import time

runners = [
    {'name':'Samantha', 'speed':3.5, 'distance_traveled':0},
    {'name':'Ben',      'speed':2.9, 'distance_traveled':0}, 
    {'name':'Luis',     'speed':1.8, 'distance_traveled':0}, 
    {'name':'Jane',     'speed':2.2, 'distance_traveled':0}
    ] 
# each elements represent an athlete. Their name and their speed. Also 'distance traveled' tracker
# let's set the speed to be units (m/s). The distance traveled is measured in (m)

# initialize a "finish line" which registers when the distance traveled is enough to win
finish_line = 30    # Distance required to win.             Units of (m)
time_tracker = 0    # Total time elapsed.                   Units of (s)
time_delta = 1      # Change in time for each iteration.    Units of (s)

# fun printing stuff
print("And we're off! Here's the standings: ")

# "while some of the athletes have not finished yet"
while any(i['distance_traveled'] < finish_line for i in runners):
    # we can use time.sleep with a while loop to register the race for each second.

    # update the distance traveled for each runner
    for r in runners:
        r["distance_traveled"] += r["speed"]*time_delta
    
    # sort the runners dict depending on who's in first place, etc.
    runners = sorted(runners, key=lambda d: d['distance_traveled'], reverse=True) 

    print(f"\nAt time {time_tracker}s the current standings are:")
    for place, r in enumerate(runners):
        print(f'{place+1}.: {r["name"]} at {r["distance_traveled"]:.1f}m')
    
    time_tracker += time_delta
    time.sleep(time_delta)
```

There's a lot of stuff I haven't added such as:

1. Changing speeds of runners as they run. Decide speeds randomly?
2. Declaring winners when they cross the finish line.
3. Other environmental factors such as wind or conditions?

Hopefully this helps! Have fun!